# A Cell Value is Returning To Its Original Value When Searching

Tags: c#, datagridview

Hi GoodMorning I'm actually having a problem with my datagridview

-After borrowing a book the value will turn to 0
[image: Datagrid View With A Zero]

-So the problem is when i start searching for that book again its showing a Value of 1 and that will allow me again to borrow that book

[image]

- Here is my code for my refresher

  ```
          connection.Open();
          OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
          command.Connection = connection;
          string query = "select *from Books";
          command.CommandText = query;

          OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
          DataTable dt = new DataTable();
          da.Fill(dt);
          dataview6.DataSource = dt;
          connection.Close();
  ```

Here is my code for my book borrowing

```
private void borrow()
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
            cmd.Connection = connection;
            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Books Set Copies = Copies -1 WHERE BOOK_NUMBER = " + bkn_num.Text + "";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Book Has Been Borrowed");
            connection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }

    }
```

Comment: How are you changing the value to zero? Are you saving that value to database?

Comment: Nope im using -1 so that when the value is 0 it will not me borrow

Comment: If you are not saving to database then it will return the old value from the database....